¿Existe el equivalente del acrónimo inglés TGIF?
En inglés hay el acrónimo "TGIF" que significa "Thank God It's Friday", para expresar que la semana de trabajo está terminando.
¿Existe un equivalente acrónimo en español?

Friday is also known as POETS day of course. Push off early tomorrow is Saturday. Perhaps there is a Spanish equivalent for that.

I've never heard that acronym before.

No conozco ningún equivalente. Creo que no somos tan amigos de los acrónimos como los anglosajones. Hay algunos errores en el final de tu frase, debería ser "la semana de trabajo está terminando". Entiendo que cuando se dice TGIF, aún queda algo de trabajo por finalizar, "está terminando" en lugar de "está terminada".

@RubioRic Gracias por la corrección.

@RubioRic También, una respuesta negativa aún es una respuesta.  ¿Pero qué se dicen los amigos los viernes?

"¡Por fin es viernes!", "¡Ya es viernes! ¡Viva!" son algunos ejemplos que me vienen a la cabeza. También hay que tener el cuenta la diferencia generacional, es decir, no sé si los jóvenes y adolescentes emplean una terminología especial o un acrónimo.

There are tons of things the other way. Not every expression exists in English either. and Spanish does not use acronyms like we do in English.

TGIF no es un acrónimo.  No se puede pronunciar como si fuera una palabra.

@WalterMitty En inglés no se dicen "TGIF" como una palabra. Se recita letra por letra.

@Lambie Por supuesto.  Y por eso estoy aquí para aprender lo que es la diferencia en este caso.

Since they don't exist, only the idea can be translated. OCHOA's answer works fine.

@Lambie But also as OCHOA pointed out, acronyms are used in Spanish, and he gave several examples of them.  Therefor it is not a stretch to imagine that there possibly could be an equivalent to TGIF.

Those are in writing. I have never heard a Spanish speaker using the letters to call someone a son of a bitch. "Eres un HDP".

@Lambie, si las usan, créeme  Por cierto respondí el comment que hizo en mi respuesta. Saludos

Era un HDP total

Partiendo del concepto de acrónimo: Sigla cuya configuración permite su pronunciación como una palabra; por ejemplo, ovni: objeto volador no identificado; TIC, tecnologías de la información y la comunicación.
Me atrevo a decir que es Español no usamos acrónimos (exceptuando nombres propios de lugares, cosas, o instituciones). Usamos acrónimos para esas cosas, el resto de acrónimos que usamos vienen principalmente del Inglés (gringo) que tiene muchísimas de esas cosas.
Ahora, yo me pregunto, con tantos acrónimos, como vocalizan los gringos estas palabras?? Al final en una conversación no dicen "TGIF" sino: Gracias a <inserte su deidad favorita acá> es viernes!

[Edito]
Por el comentario de Lambie me doy cuenta que no solo los gringos los usan. Yo por el hecho que vengo de cerca de ellos, es que los nombré específicamente, pero es bueno saber que otros países de habla inglesa también los usan 
Debo aclarar algo. En algunos países como México, Argentina y no recuerdo otros, si usan algunos acrónimos, más que todo para insultos, por ejemplo: CTM, HP, HDP, PLGD... entre otros.
Por cierto CTM (versión MX) el que me dio voto negativo (downvote) jajajkasl 

Creo que seria mejor no decir tanto los gringos porque los ingleses dicen eso y probablemente los australianos tambien.

Yo no iría tan lejos como para indicar que los hispanohablantes no usamos acrónimos. Desde que se popularizaron los SMS (ahora sustituidos por whatsapp y variantes) tenemos por ejemplo: TQM

@Lambie ¡Soy verdadero gringo! Y estoy orgulloso de ello (pero es una broma de mi)

Gracias, OCHOA. :) Pero HDP es por escrito, ¿verdad? No creo que se diga...

Claro que lo dicen literalmente HDP. La verdad es que cada vez voy "abriendo los ojos" y viendo que si usamos acrónimos como lo menciona @RubioRic en su comentario anterior. HDP se dice cuando por (lo que sea) no se puede decir Hijo de...  Pero estos términos así, los usan en su mayoría, los jóvenes. PD: Gringos es de cariño jajajakajskl cada país tiene su apodo/mote/nick y ese es el de ellos. Acá en España a los Ingleses les dicen Guiris y ni idea del porqué, solo es así

Yo leo TQM y pienso en Total Quality Management.

En español, no hay un acrónimo tan popular y específico como “TGIF” en inglés. Sin embargo, algunas personas usan expresiones como “¡Por fin es viernes!” o “¡Gracias a Dios es viernes!” para expresar la misma idea.

Respuesta copiada de ChatGPT

@Danielillo Quiero una prueba. Yo recién le pregunté a ChatGPT y esto me respondió: ‘Sí, en español también hay acrónimos similares que se usan para expresar la alegría de que ha llegado el fin de semana. Aunque no hay un equivalente exacto a "TGIF", algunas personas utilizan "TGIF" tal cual o frases como "¡Por fin viernes!" para expresar lo mismo. En cuanto a acrónimos en español, no es tan común, pero podrías encontrar algo como "PFF" para "Por Fin es Viernes". Sin embargo, "TGIF" se ha popularizado mucho y es entendible en contextos de habla hispana también.’ Nada que ver.

O sea, exactamente lo mismo que la respuesta! Obviamente las pruebas no hay que dártelas a ti. El seguimiento de respuestas generadas por inteligencia artificial de este usuario no hace referencia a solo una, sino a todas.
